# How to load data into a Postgres table skipping the header row and adding serial primary key

Tags: postgresql, header, copy, primary-key

I have a large tab delimited data file of the form

fieldA   fieldB   fieldC
xxx      123      456
yyyyy    32       1654
...

I would like to load it into a table that has a serial primary key, e.g.

```
create table my_data (
    ID serial primary key,
    fieldA varchar(10),
    fieldB int,
    fieldC int
)
```

I would like to use a command like

```
COPY 'data.txt' TO my_data (HEADER TRUE)
```

Two issues:

1) The file contains a header row, but copy only allows the HEADER option on CSV files. It's a big data file and I would prefer not to have to create an extra copy just to remove one header row. Any work arounds?

2) The ID serial primary key needs to be generated, it is not in the data file. Do I have to first use COPY to load a temp table and then do an INSERT specifying the fields? Again, a big file and would prefer to avoid unnecessary data moves.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use CSV format, but specify TAB as the separator. This allows you to skip the header line.

```
COPY my_data(fieldA, fieldB, fieldC)
  FROM 'data.txt'
  WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER e'\t'
  ;
```